# Change the whole content of iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a textarea in which I wan't to add HTML code that will compose a full webpage, and as I type this content will be rendered in an iframe

For example in the textarea I'll write the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Live generate</title>
        <style></style>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

My problem is that I don't know how to access the iFrame in order to change it's full content so that it matches the one above

Comment: `iframes` must have a `src` attribute - so you will need to point the `iframe` at a source file and then modify the `body` of the `iframe`

Comment: @ManseUK The `src` attribute is not required.

Answer (score 2):

you should be able to get the iframe by its id with document.getElementsById or through jquery and then get its document, open it and write to it.

Like:

```
var iframe = $("iframe"); // or by Id $("#myIframeId")
var doc = iframe.document;

doc.open();
doc.write($("#myTextArea").text());
doc.close();
```

Comment: Does jQuery do the trick without using `contentWindow`-property of the `iframe`?

Comment: I'm sorry, but the code above doesn't work in Chrome. It says Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'open' of undefined

Comment: A friend suggested this link and it works http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1021687

Comment: No problem. Thanks for wanting to help